# Ahrefs reports "Fetching robots.txt took too long"

Tags: web-crawlers, robots.txt, ahrefs

My robots:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /wp-admin
Disallow: /sistema
Disallow: /site
Disallow: /old

Sitemap: http://www.example.com.br/page-sitemap.xml
```

In the google test tool: https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/robots-testing-tool is going normal: 'allowed'

But at ahref I have the feedback:

> Fetching robots.txt took too long

I have already asked the hosting staff to see for us if there is any blocking of the crawler or the ips used by ahrefs and there is not.

I have already disabled all plugins on the site and nothing

Comment: Is your `robots.txt` file a static file or dynamically generated at the time of request?

Comment: `robots.txt` is static. When accessing robots.txt through the browser, its content is always the same

Comment: Maybe the problem is with ahrefs servers/location? To clarify, GSC/Google isn't actually reporting any problem with your `robots.txt` file?

Comment: Just wondered... is the `robots.txt` request being redirected from HTTP to HTTPS?

Comment: Both, but the site was at http

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed hosting and right after I tested the ahrefs crawler and everything worked perfectly, probably something from the host was blocking ahrefs ips.

Incredible is that the hosting staff did not know how to solve it.